# Xcode: App quits without error

Tags: ios, xcode, crash

I'm having a weird bug on Xcode (6.1.1). My app is exiting without an error. It's the same behavior that happens when we click on the stop button on Xcode. It seems that the exit() method is being called, but it's not. I already added an exception breakpoint, but could not find anything.

Any tips?

Comment: Is it also happening in the simulator? If not it could be that you are building with a distribution provisioning profile

Comment: To go along with the possibly incorrect provisioning profile, what does the device log say when the app fails? If you don't already know, you can watch the device log in the "Devices" window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tied to read the registers by putting an exception breakpoint.

Go to Exceptions tab and click on 'Add Exception Breakpoint' using the + at the bottom left corner.A crash with no error can be the source of lot's of consequences such as memory issue.